# How to create a blinking react View

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can someone help me out how I can create a blink-able react-native component?

So basically, this is what I have done

```
class Blinkable extends PureComponent {

state = {
    blinkComponentVisibility: false
 }  

 blink () {
        this.setState({blinkComponentVisibility: !  blinkComponentVisibility})
        console.log(this.state)
     }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {this.blink}, 3000)
    }

render () {
  if (i === currentProgress) {
            if (this.state.blinkComponentVisibility) {
            progressBarArray.push(
                <View
                style={{
                    width: widthOfIndividualBlog,
                    backgroundColor: colorOfProgressBar,
                    height: heightOfProgressBar
                }}
                key={i}
            ></View>)
  }
}



return (
            <View>

                <View style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}>{progressBarArray}</View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

With the above code, I was expecting my component to blink but nothing happens rather I see the following **logs** in console

> RCTLog.js:47 Could not locate shadow view with tag #363, this is
>   probably caused by a temporary inconsistency between native views and
>   shadow views

Can someone please help me in figuring out what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`this.setState({blinkComponentVisibility: !  blinkComponentVisibility})` should be `this.setState({blinkComponentVisibility: !  this.state.blinkComponentVisibility})`

and in your set timout you need to call the function

`setTimeout(() => this.blink(), 3000)`